# we are in receipt of something

Tags: meaning, idioms, translation

what does it mean "`to be in receipt of something`"?

I have checked the meaning but have not figured it out fully, since I am a translator I need a literal translation for me to build out a meaningful, usable sentence in my own language.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***To be in receipt of*** is a phrase to acknowledge that something has been received, as in "I am in receipt of the payment you sent last week."

Answer (score 4):

“To be in receipt of *s.t.”* is an idiom that simply means “to have received *s.t.”*

O.E.D. s.v. *receive n:*

> 3.a. The action of receiving something, or the fact of something being received, into one’s possession or custody. In modern use freq. *in receipt of.*

Answer (score 1):

To be "in receipt of" something is, I believe, old, and to us rather stilted, business English phrasing, the sort of language used by shopkeepers in the early 19th century, meaning merely "received".  Such language remained in common use until the mid 20th century, and is occasionally still found.  Another example is "[I am in receipt of] your favor of the 18th ult.", meaning "I received the letter or note you wrote me dated the 18th of last month".

Answer (score 0):

This is an expression which confirms one has received something.

For example:

> I am in receipt of funds transferred to my bank account

This confirms that the funds were received.